# In Python how to remove a range of lines from a file without using fileinput module

Tags: python, file-io

I am trying to remove a range of lines passed from the command line to a Python script. That means, I will pass the input file name, starting line number(from where to start removing)  and number of lines to be removed from the input file. I have tried that using fileinput module and that is working.
Command to run from my unix prompt is :

python script.py inputfile 2 6

Below is the code for that :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import fileinput
import sys

filename, start, upto = sys.argv[1:4]
start, upto = int(start), int(upto)

for line in fileinput.input(filename, inplace=1, backup='.orig'):

    if start <= fileinput.lineno() < start + upto:
        pass
    else:
        print line[:-1]

fileinput.close()
```

However, my requirement is to do the same without using fileinput. I have been able to try upto some extent and below is my tried code. The output should exactly be as same as the previous code. Keeping a back up file can be ignored though. If anybody can  help me to achieve the requirement, would be of great help. Thanks.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#import fileinput
import sys

filename, start, upto = sys.argv[1:4]
start, upto = int(start), int(upto)

f =  open(filename, "r+")
for lineno, line in enumerate(f):

    if start <= lineno < start + upto:
        length = len(line)
        f.seek(-length, 1)
        f.write("")

f.close()
```

Comment: So, you need to read a file and remove some line from it and save it again on disk. You can open two files, one for reading and another for writing, and just loop over the lines of the input file. Then you can write the lines you want in the output file and skipping the ones you don't want.

Comment: @Luiz de Prá ..That is fine. However, I do not want to do it that way.

Comment: How about reading the entire file into memory and then opening it again, over-writing it entirely with the selected lines only?

Comment: Why can't you use the `fileinput` module?  It uses the approach of writing to a new file first and rotating it in place, by the way.  This approach is the easiest and most robust approach to this problem, and it is what I recommend you to do.

Answer (score 0):

**With second file**

```
with open(fileinput) as fin, with open(fileoutput) as fout:
    for i,l in fin:
        if start <= i < start + upto:
            fout.write("%s\n"%l)
```

**In-memory**

If you are adamant about not using a second file, how about loading the entire file into memory, e.g.

```
import sys

filename, start, upto = sys.argv[1:4]
start, upto = int(start), int(upto)

fread = open(filename)
original = list(fread)
fread.close()

fileinput = open(filename, "w")
for line in original:
    if start <= fileinput.lineno() < start + upto:
        pass
    else:
        fileinput.write("%s\n" % line)

fileinput.close()
```

You might want to consider using context managers for file i/o. Also replacing with the list of lines allows you to simply slice into that list:

```
import sys

filename, start, upto = sys.argv[1:4]
start, upto = int(start), int(upto)

with open(filename) as fread:
    original = list(fread)

with open(filename, "w") as fileinput:
    for line in original[start:start+upto]:
        fileinput.write("%s\n" % line)
```

Comment: @jmtez I apologize that I should have been more specific about the requiremnt. It has to be memory efficient. If it is a huge file, I want to avoid reading it into a list.

Comment: @H.Burns - in that case I don't think this can be done; even `fileinput` uses a backup file under the hood...

Comment: "Optional in-place filtering: if the keyword argument inplace=1 is passed to fileinput.input() or to the FileInput constructor, the file is moved to a backup file and standard output is directed to the input file (if a file of the same name as the backup file already exists, it will be replaced silently)."

Comment: Actually, nope... not getting it to over-write the original data.

Comment: @jmtez You are reading it into a list. The one I tried with seek(), can't it be done with seek() and tell() or the like ?

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(dir+"file_name.txt", 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    for index, line in enumerate(lines):
        if "range_match_upper_part" in line:
            break
    for index_2, line in enumerate(lines):
        if "range_match_lower_part" in line:
            break
    for ll in range (index, index_2)):
        lines[ll]=''
    with open(save_dir + "save_file.txt", "w") as file:
        contents = "".join(lines)
        file.write(contents)

file.close()
print("DONE")
```